# Null pointer exception populating a new array

Tags: java, arrays, nullpointerexception

I am trying to implement a vector of generic data type where the type is taken as input from the user such as :

```
package com.example.genericvector;

import java.util.Scanner;


public class GenericVector <generic_type>{

    private int length;
    private generic_type [] vector;

    GenericVector(generic_type element){
        this.vector[0] = element;
    }


    public void allocate_size(int length){

    }
    public void push_back(generic_type element){

    }
    public void display(generic_type [] vector){

        for(generic_type element : vector)
            System.out.print(element);

        System.out.println();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter the data type of vector : ");
        String vector_type = scanner.next();

        switch (vector_type){
            case "integer":
                GenericVector <Integer> vector_int = new GenericVector <Integer>(new Integer(10));
                break;
            case "double":
                GenericVector <Double> vector_double = new GenericVector <Double>(new Double(10.57));
                break;
            default:
                System.out.print("Invalid data type");
        }
    }
}
```

Upon running the above code I get the following as output:

```
    Enter the data type of vector : integer
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.example.genericvector.GenericVector.<init>(GenericVector.java:12)
    at com.example.genericvector.GenericVector.main(GenericVector.java:40)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I am pretty new to Java, so any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Just for the record - in case you found any of the answers helpful, you can still accept it; gives a little push to your reputation too.

Answer (score 1):

```
private generic_type [] vector;
```

only **declares** a field (array) of your generic type. But initially, the array is **null**.

Something like

```
private generic_type [] vector = new generic_type[10];
```

initializes that field with a new vector (but please note that the individual array slots are all **null** at this point, too). But, uups, commentors are right ... that is one of the deficiencies of generics and arrays, you **can't** use new[] for generic types. On the other hand, arrays have a fixed size in Java; so you would have to constantly check if you have to grow/shrink that underlying array! Thus a *working* solution could be:

```
private List<T> vector = new ArrayList<>();
```

for example (using the existing Java collection classes here).

Final note: by convention, generic types are denoted using single upperchase characters. So it should be `GenericVector<T>` instead of `generic_type`.

Comment: Note that  `new generic_type[10]` is not possible.

Comment: My bad - you are right. Thanks for the input!

Comment: Yup just checked it up @Thomas.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't intialize the array `vector` and thus `this.vector[0]` will throw a NullPointerException.

Have a look here on how to create a generic array instance:[How to create a generic array in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/529085/how-to-create-a-generic-array-in-java)

Edit: your constructor or allocate_size() method would then contain something like this:

```
vector = (generic_type[]) Array.newInstance(element.getClass(), length);
```

Also note that you need to provide a length for your array so in the constructor you're calling the array must be initialized to have at least length 1, otherwise `vector[0]` will result in an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.

Comment: How will I make my vector generalizable then, as I would have to set it to the same data type with what I initialize it with?

Comment: @AbhijeetMohanty I'v already edited my question with a link that should explain what you need to do.

Comment: Great help, thanks a ton. Only thing how do I get to the bottom of understanding the code given by your link @Thomas